# php two actions in one form

Tags: forms, button, submit, action

I have question about the other options... i have form like this...

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
.
.
.
.
<button class="btn btn-success"  name="submit_mult" type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

I have another button called (delete) inside of above form in same page that will take action to delete.php page.

But the delete button is need to action to delete.php, but is already used up with action="edit.php" see above  codes

How can i solve that to make both works!

AM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `formaction` attribute on the button:

```
<button type="submit" formaction="delete.php">Delete</button>
```

This overrides the `action` attribute of the form when you click on that button.